# Add logging with default spring logging?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following in my application.properties file:

```
# logging
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.pattern.file= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
logging.file=/tmp/application.log
```

I would like to add logging in my controller as follows:

```
public String index(Model model) {
    logger.debug("User landed on homepage!");
    return "register";
}
```

However, every example I have seen involves importing `log4j` and setting a bunch of additional properties in the application.properties file. Is this required, or is there a way to do debugging 'directly from' Spring, so to speak? In the above example, what would be the simplest way to get a working example of logging the statement "User landed on homepage"!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use `slf4j` its easy to use and works!

Here's an Example:

```
public class YourClass {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);

    public String index(Model model) {
        LOG.debug("User landed on homepage!");
        return "register";
    }

}
```

Comment: slf4j is a good argument but you could sell it better :) The great value of slf4j is that it is a logging facade. It accepts a lot of distinct implementations and also allows to switch to another logging implementation very easily.

Comment: @davidxxx couldn't have said it better myself (I was in a rush when I answered)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to add the following to `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(LoginApplication.class, args);
    BasicConfigurator.configure(); // this line

}
```

The you can call `log4j` without having to add any additional properties. For example:

```
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @GetMapping
    public String index(Model model) {

        logger.debug("User landed on homepage!");
        return 

    }
}
```